# How to determine which object in a special relativity physics problem has proper time?

Tags: special-relativity

I'm having some difficulty determining which object/location should have proper time applied to it in relativity physics problems.

Example:

If an electron travels at 40% the speed of light then collides with a phosphorus molecule in a TV screen, how much mass would be sensed by an observer stationed on the molecule?

My inclination is to give the molecule proper time, as that is where the measurement is happening.

If I do that:
$m=\gamma{m}_0$ -> $m_0=\frac{m}{\gamma}$

$v=0.4c=1.199*10^8 \frac{m}{s}$

$m_e=9.109*10^{-31} kg$

So $m_0=\frac{9.109*10^{-31} kg}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{(1.199*10^8 \frac{m}{s})^2}{(2.9979*10^8 \frac{m}{s})^2}}}}$ = $9.109*10^{-31}*\sqrt{1-\frac{(1.199*10^8 \frac{m}{s})^2}{(2.9979*10^8 \frac{m}{s})^2}}$

And I get: $8.3487*10^{-31}$, but the answer is: $9.9385*10^{-31}$

If I instead multiply by $\gamma$ instead of its reciprocal, I get the correct answer, which makes me think I have selected the wrong 'object' to use for proper time.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean with "applying proper time" to an object?

Comment: How to determine which object/location to use for $m_0$ vs $m$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate problems here that I can help you with - terminology, and math.

---

**First problem: you're not using the term "proper time"...erm...properly.**

The proper time of an object is the time that a clock attached to that object would read - nothing more, nothing less.  So if you're wearing a watch right now, it will tell you **your** proper time whether you're sitting on the Earth or rocketing around in your spaceship.

The proper time doesn't really have anything to do with this problem - I suspect you're thinking of "proper time" as in "real time" or "actual time".  I suspect you are trying to figure out which object is "really at rest" and which is "moving", which is a misconception - it's all, literally, relative.

---

**Second problem:  You aren't solving for the quantity that the problem asks for.**

If you are at rest relative to a phosphorus molecule on a screen, and an electron is whizzing towards you at 0.4c, then the mass of the electron appears to be greater than if the electron were at rest.  It has nothing to do with proper time - this is a result of mass-energy equivalence ([see this for a derivation of the formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#The_relativistic_energy-momentum_equation)).  Basically, the kinetic energy of the electron contributes to its mass!  So, you're **never** going to have a situation in which the electron has less mass than its rest mass.

The long and the short of it is that you actually started with the right formula:

$$m = \gamma m_0$$

However, you went off the rails when you started plugging things in.  The quantity you are actually looking for (the mass that you would measure from the rest frame of the molecule) is $m$, not $m_0$!  So, you don't need to solve for $m_0$, just find $m$.

Other than the fact that you were solving for the wrong quantity, you did everything right.

Comment: My one complaint about this answer is that it's not clear about the difference between relativistic mass (an outdated concept) and rest mass. Otherwise, very nicely explained.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense.  So if object x is moving towards observer y, then $m_0$ is the rest mass of the object x and $m$ is the relativistic mass of the same object?

Comment: @DavidZ yes, I've received that complaint before.  When I learned SR, I learned that the "rest mass" of an object is the mass as measured in its rest frame, and the "relativistic mass" (a.k.a. "mass") is the mass of an object as measured in an arbitrary frame.  What is the preferred terminology now?

Comment: @Irongrave, yes, that's correct, although I'm told that it's not the preferred terminology.

Comment: @Brionius the modern terminology, as I know it, is that what you learned to call "rest mass", formerly denoted $m_0$, is simply called "mass" and denoted $m$, and "relativistic mass", formerly denoted $m$, is now just "energy" or "total energy" $E$. Or more precisely, instead of talking about relativistic mass, we talk about energy, which differs by a factor of $c^2$. For example, the (total) energy of an object is its mass energy plus its kinetic energy, and the total energy increases with velocity, but the mass never changes. (My main complaint is with the use of $m$ for relativistic mass.)